# Create document from the result value of a Map Reduce Agregation

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mapreduce, mongodb-query, reduce

I wrote a Map/Reduce procedure which returns (obviously) a collections of key/value documents :

```
output { 
    _id: blabla,
    value: {
         ga: blabl,
         bu: blab,
         zo: bla,
         meu: bl
    }
}
```

But what I ultimately want is the following collection, getting rid of the value, and retrieving it's elements to create a new document, easier to manipulate, and more similar to the result of an aggregate :

```
collection {
   ga: blabl,
   bu: blab,
   zo: bla,
   meu: bl
}
```

Is there a way to do that during the map reduce process ? I guess it's a common concern, but I can't find any explanation.

=======================================================================

Following the discussion : Why did I tried to use Map/Reduce, and thought an aggregation wouldn't fit :

Here is, more precisely, an exemple of my data :

```
events collection 
{
   recipient_id: recip1,       //my aggregation key
   EventType: type1,           //50 distinct values
   EventOrganizer: orgaName1,  //10 distinct values
   date_sent: jj/mm/aaaa,      //always provided
   date_action1: jj/mm/aaaa,   //may be null
   date_action2: jj/mm/aaaa    //may be null
},
{
   recipient_id: recip2, 
   EventType: type1, 
   EventOrganizer: orgaName1, 
   date_sent: jj/mm/aaaa, 
   date_action1: jj/mm/aaaa, 
   date_action2: jj/mm/aaaa
},
{
   recipient_id: recip1, 
   EventType: type2, 
   EventOrganizer: orgaName1, 
   date_sent: jj/mm/aaaa, 
   date_action1: jj/mm/aaaa, 
   date_action2: jj/mm/aaaa
},etc.
```

What I want :

```
contacts collection 
{
   recipient_id: recip1,       //my aggregation key
   distinctNbOfEvents:
   distinctNbOfOrganizers:
   listDates:[jj//mm/aaaa,jj/mm/aaaa], //sorted list of each date_sent
   organizers:{
        orgaName1: nb_events, 
        orgaName2: nb_events,
        ...
        orgaNamek: nb_events
   }                          //for each organizer, the number of events organized for this recipient
   hasAction1:                //boolean, is there at least 1 event with a date_action1 not null
   hasAction2:                //boolean, is there at least 1 event with a date_action2 not null
   nbOfEvents:
   rateOfAction1:             //(nb of date_action1 not null)/(nb of events)
   rateOfAction2:             //(nb of date_action2 not null)/(nb of date_action1 not null)   
   avgDelay1:                 //between an event date_sent and the related action 1 if not null
   avgDelay2:                 //between an event date_sent and the related action 2 if not null
   sentFrequency:             //Avg number of days between the date_sent of two consecutives events, can be calculated as (more recent - more ancient)/(nbOfEvents -1)
}
```

What I thought I couldn't do with aggregate : listDates, organizers, sentFrequency.